# Can't set value to data attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

From some reason I can't figure out, the `$('element').data('data_attribute_name', 'value');` syntax doesn't work here:

HTML:

```
<ul class="main_menu__list" data-scheme="light">
...
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.main_menu__list').data('scheme', 'dark');
$('.main_menu__list').css('border', '10px solid yellow');
```

The second line does work (yellow border applied), the second one does nothing. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
$('.main_menu__list').attr('data-scheme', 'dark');
```

instead of this :

```
$('.main_menu__list').data('scheme', 'dark');
```

Comment: Ah yep it does now, cache issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first line is working fine. The `data()` method stores the values in an in-memory cache so that it's faster (at least in theory) due to having to query the DOM less often. It does not update the DOM at all.

So long as you also use the getter of `data()` to retrieve the value this works absolutely fine:

```js
var $list = $('.main_menu__list');

$list.data('scheme', 'dark').css('border', '10px solid yellow');

// to retrieve the attribute:

console.log($list.data('scheme')); // 'dark'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main_menu__list" data-scheme="light"></ul>
```

> even using attr() as suggested in another answer it still doesn't change it!

Yep, it does. You can check it in the DOM inspector after running this snippet:

```js
var $list = $('.main_menu__list');

$list.attr('data-scheme', 'dark').css('border', '10px solid yellow');

// to retrieve the attribute:

console.log($list.data('scheme')); // 'dark'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main_menu__list" data-scheme="light"></ul>
```

Comment: So data() doesn't change the DOM. Right but even using attr() as suggested in another answer it still doesn't change it!

Comment: Yes it does. I updated my answer to show you the DOM being updated through `attr()` - although I'd strongly suggest you stick with using `data()` instead

Comment: I had a cache issue, attr() works now. But trying to change the value of my "data-scheme" attribute definitely doesn't work :(